# Web service returns [] rather than the actual List

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am going through legacy code and not that familiar with VB or Webservices tbh.  I need this to display as an array but when running the operation, it will not return the actual list items. I get the following instead:

```
anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" d1p1:type="q1:string">[]</anyType
```

What am I missing?

```
Public Shared Function GetVehicleFromVINforDecode(ByVal vin As String)

    Dim VINlist As New List(Of VINResult)
    Dim strPattern As String
    strPattern = GetVinPattern(vin)


    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.CKConnectionString)

        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("select * from VehicleData.dbo.vin_pattern where vin_pattern = '" & strPattern & "'", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Using r As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader

            While r.Read()

                Dim VINitem = New VINResult()


                VINitem.Make = (r("Make"))
                VINitem.Model = (r("Model"))
                VINitem.Year = (r("Year"))
                VINitem.Cylinders = (r("DEF_ENGINE_CYLINDERS"))
                VINitem.Drive = (r("DRIVE_TYPE"))
                VINitem.Liters = (r("DEF_ENGINE_SIZE"))
                VINitem.Style = (r("Style"))
                VINitem.TransmissionSpeed = (r("DEF_TRANS_SPEEDS"))
                VINitem.TransmissionType = (r("DEF_TRANS_TYPE"))
                VINitem.Trim = (r("Trim"))
                VINitem.FuelType = (r("FUEL_TYPE"))

                VINlist.AddRange(VINitem)


            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    Return VINlist

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In case my answer doesn't work you might want to specify how you are calling this and what kind of web service you're using, otherwise this'll only turn into a guessing game.

Comment: And since you're new here, please take a moment to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how this site works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and an array are not the same things, and from my experience here on Stack Overflow web services usually don't have very good support for the former.

Try calling [**`ToArray()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) on the list when returning it in order to convert it into a regular array:

```
Return VINlist.ToArray()
```